Want to check tls version of RDS posgreesql, S3 , Cognito and SNS
I want to know how I can check tls version for following services in aws

RDS posgreesql
S3
SNS
Cognito


Have you try with openssl? openssl s_client -connect example.org:443 -brief|grep Protocol

for RDS we don't have SSH is there any other way through console?

What network connectivity options do you have? If you only want to validate from the console, the question should state that.

Easiest is probably to install openssl on an EC2 instance to check using openssl as Romeo suggested above. Otherwise From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/DataDurability.html : "We require TLS 1.2 and recommend TLS 1.3.". To check RDS you could try making a public RDS instance, allocate a public IP and a route to the internet, then use a TLS version checker. I'm not sure they'll work against RDS the same way they do against web servers.
